# Load image on canvas Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas, windows-phone-7.1

I am choosing image using **PhotoChooserTask**. 
I am trying to load selected image on canvas but not able to load.

Here is my code

```
 void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            string path = e.OriginalFileName;
            Uri uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);

            ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);

            image.Height = paint.Height;
            image.Width = paint.Width;

            image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, img);

            Canvas.SetLeft(image, 50);
            Canvas.SetTop(image, 50);

            paint.Children.Add(image);
        }
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
 <Canvas x:Name="paint" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,95,0,139" >

 </Canvas>
```

I am getting why this is not working. Is there any change in my code?

Comment: Should you be setting the position of the image in the canvas via the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attributes? Eg. `Canvas.SetLeft(image, 10); Canvas.SetTop(image, 10);`

Comment: Give the image a width and height

Comment: give your canvas a width and a height

Comment: could you try to change this `UriKind.Relative` to `UriKind.Absolute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added my comment as an answer as I'm pretty sure this is the problem.

Should you be setting the position of the image in the canvas via the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attributes? Eg.

```
Canvas.SetLeft(image, 10); 
Canvas.SetTop(image, 10); 
paint.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `path` and `uri` are creating a valid source property for the image as it seems to be working correctly for me.

Comment: Yes, I am selecting images from isolated storage by using PhotoChooserTask.